# Difficulty understanding someones source code to a solution of an IOI problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, std-pair

Here is the link to the problem: https://ioi2019.az/source/Tasks/Day1/Shoes/NGA.pdf

Here is a brief explanation about the **problem statemen**t:

You are given an integer **n** in the range **1≤n≤1e5** which will be representing the amount of positive integers inside of the array, as-well as the amount of negative integers in an array(so the total size of the array will be **2n**).

The problem wants you to find the minimum number of swaps needed in the array such that the negative value of a number and the absolute value of that negative number are adjacent to each other(**such that -x is to the right of x)**

Example:

n = 2;

the array inputed = {2, 1, -1, -2}

The minimum number of operations will be four:

2,1,-1,-2: 0 swaps

2,-1,1,-2: 1 swap(swapping  1 and -1)

2,-1,-2,1: 2 swaps (swapping 1 and -2)

2,-2,-1,1: 3 swaps (swapping -1 and -2)

-2,2,-1,1: 4 swaps (swapping 2 and -2)

The final answer will be four.

Another example:

the array inputed = {-2, 2, 2, -2, -2, 2}

The minimum swaps is one. Because we can just swap elements at index 2 and 3.

Final array: {-2,2,-2,2,-2,2}

---

When doing this question I got wrong answer and I decided to look at someones source code on git hub.

Here is the source code:

```
#include "shoes.h"
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define sz(v) ((int)(v).size())
using namespace std;
using lint = long long;
using pi = pair<int, int>;
const int MAXN = 200005;

struct bit{
    int tree[MAXN];
    void add(int x, int v){
        for(int i=x; i<MAXN; i+=i&-i) tree[i] += v;
    }
    int query(int x){
        int ret = 0;
        for(int i=x; i; i-=i&-i) ret += tree[i];
        return ret;
    }
}bit;


lint count_swaps(vector<int> s) {
    int n = sz(s) / 2;
    lint ret = 0;
    vector<pi> v;
    vector<pi> ord[MAXN];
    for(int i=0; i<sz(s); i++){
        ord[abs(s[i])].emplace_back(s[i], i);
    }
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        sort(ord[i].begin(), ord[i].end());
        for(int j=0; j<sz(ord[i])/2; j++){
            int l = ord[i][j].second;
            int r = ord[i][j + sz(ord[i])/2].second; //confusion starts here all the way to the buttom
            if(l > r){
                swap(l, r);
                ret++;
            }
            v.emplace_back(l + 1, r + 1);
        }
    }
    for(int i=1; i<=2*n; i++) bit.add(i, 1);
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    for(auto &i : v){
        ret += bit.query(i.second - 1) - bit.query(i.first);
        bit.add(i.first, -1);
        bit.add(i.second, -1);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

However, I dont think I understand the this code too well.

I understand what the functions **add** and **query** in BIT do I'm just confused on where I commented on the code all the way to the bottom. I dont understand what it does and what the purpose of that is.

Can someone walk through what this code is doing? Or give any suggestions to how I should **properly and efficiently** approach this problem(even maybe your solutions?). Thank you.

Comment: `#define sz(v) ((int)(v).size()) using namespace std;`, etc.. Why these crazy macros?  This is undoubtedly from one of those "competitive programming" websites.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It just copied someones exact source code, I can change it without macros if you like. I found this source code on git hub.

Comment: It might help to walk through the code line by line with some very small examples. If it's any consolation I don't understand the code either.

Comment: @Rainier1 [Cargo-cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) should be avoided.  Also, that solution can blow out the stack memory with declarations like this: `vector<pi> ord[MAXN];`.  No real-world programmer would blindly declare 200000+ `std::vector`'s.

Comment: Wherever you got the source from, please don't go back there. The source is *bad* and not worth attempting to learn anything from (unless you want to see plenty of bad habits).

Comment: "Here is the link to ..." - *Please* don't link to problems, code or anything else. A Stackoverflow question should be *self contained* and include *all* relevant information directly *in the question*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I seen worse source for a competition sites. And even though the code could be improved there might still be something to be gained by understanding the algorithm.

Comment: Wow!  There is a lot to learn from that code, it is brimming with "how not to do C++".

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` - No, no, *no*! Don't *ever* do that.

Comment: [Wasn't IOI the bad guys?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ready_Player_One)

Comment: @Rainier1 The entire huge vector seems to be able to be replaced by `std::map<int, std::pair<int,int>>`.  No need to sort, no need to declare 200005 vectors.  One thing you need to realize about these competition websites -- all they care about is if the code you wrote solves the problem.  The code could be complete slop, it doesn't matter.  The issue is that a lot of the slop is posted here by new programmers who don't understand it, and we have to wade through it, or give advice to "never code this way".

Comment: I've edited the post everyone. I really tried my best in adding more clarity.

Comment: Must read: [The International Obfuscated C Code Contest](https://www.ioccc.org/)

Comment: Which part do you not understand?

Comment: People don't seem to accept that macros and `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` exist for a reason. This include had always made my life easier. It is better than writing `#include <vector>`, `#include <list>`, `#include <map>`, `#include <set>`, `#include <deque>`, `#include <stack>`, `#include <bitset>`, `#include <algorithm>`, `#include <functional>`, `#include <numeric>`, `#include <utility>`, `#include <sstream>`, `#include <iostream>`, `#include <iomanip>`, `#include <cstdio>`, `#include <cmath>`, `#include <cstdlib>`, `#include <ctime>`, `#include <queue>`, etc., isn't it?

Comment: This should be an ended discussion. I always see people downvoting and complaining about `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` even when the focus of the question has nothing to do with it, ignoring the fact that it is there for a simple reason: **the include itself doesn't matter here**. People should focus on the content instead of complaining about the includes.

Comment: @Daniel -- The problem is that the code with that header will not compile for a major brand of compiler that works for Windows, namely Microsoft Visual C++.  The code now has to be reworked and retooled on the helper's end to even attempt to duplicate the error.   Second, I doubt any solution requires all of those headers.  If the solution uses `vector` and `cout`, then the only includes are `<vector>` and `<iostream>`.  Then not only will there not be any complaints, the code will actually work for all compilers and all who would like to help out.  Is that too much to ask for?

Comment: @ThomasSablik OP indicated which part in a comment in the code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie my guess is busy competitive programmers don't want to waste time on carefully choosing headers and macros. They probably have a few standard starting templates they are used to and can quickly move from.

Comment: @גלעדברקן This is not a competitive programming website.  There is no competition going on here.  Thus the OP has plenty of time to make the code presentable *here*.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that's fair. A little effort doesn't hurt and could help this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int r = ord[i][j + sz(ord[i])/2].second;
```

We've sorted the tuples of one shoe size in a vector of `<size, idx>`, which means all the negatives of this size take up the first half of `ord[i]`, and all the positives are in the second half.

```
if (l > r){
  swap(l, r);
  ret++;
}
```

After our sort on size, the indexes of each corresponding pair may not be ordered with the negative before the positive. Each one of those costs a swap.

```
v.emplace_back(l + 1, r + 1);
```

insert into `v` our interval for the corresponding pair of shoes of size `i`.

```
for(int i=1; i<=2*n; i++) bit.add(i, 1);
sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Add the value of 1 in our segment-sum tree for each index location of a shoe. Sort the shoe intervals.

```
for(auto &i : v){
  ret += bit.query(i.second - 1) - bit.query(i.first);
```

For each pair of shoes in `v`, the number of swaps needed is the number of shoes left in between them, expressed in the sum of the segment.

```
bit.add(i.first, -1);
bit.add(i.second, -1);
```

Remove the pair of shoes from the tree so a new segment sum won't include them. We can do this since the shoe intervals are processed left to right, which means no "inner" pair of shoes gets processed before an outer pair.

Comment: thank you for this explanation. I understand most things now but im confused why we add l+1 and r+1 instead of l and r and why we subtract i.second from one and not i.first. Besides that thank you very much for this explanation.

Comment: @Rainier1 the tree uses non zero-based indexes. The first index is 1 so we add 1 to `l` and `r` to offset so they work in the tree lookup. Your second question I think is about `bit.query(i.second - 1)`. I'm not 100% sure but I believe it's another correction on the query interval. `bit.query` is a prefix sum. If we have [1, 1, 1, 1] values, a query on 4 will return 4 and a query on 1 will return 1. 4 - 1 = 3 is incorrect, though. We want 2, which is the number of 1's between 1 and 4. So we start on 3: 3 - 1 = 2.